# How do I enable SHA-2 Support on a windows 2012 RTM

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, windows-update

How can I find the updated necessary to enable SHA-2 support on Windows 2012 RTM.

- Windows update shows no patches available
- Searches on Microsoft sites show patches for 2008 and mention 2012 but there does not seem to be a 2012 patch

Going to 2012R2 is a larger jump than we'd like to take at this moment, so we are looking for the SHA-2 enabling update as a standalone.

Comment: Windows Server 2012 already supports SHA2. "Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows RT, and Windows RT 8.1 do not require this update because SHA-2 signing and verification functionality is already included in these operating systems. "  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/security-updates/securityadvisories/2015/3033929

Comment: Hmm, so the driver fails with a 577 error if it is signed with a cert with a sha2 thumbprint.  signtool claims the driver is OK and chain of trust complete when I check the driver cert on that machine.  Finally, an earlier driver with a cert with a sha-1 thumprint cert is OK. If we resign with the newer cert it fails.   So, I suspect SHA-2 support isn't 100%